# R - Selecting and renaming iterateratively a column by a character

Tags: r, select, rename

I got a large dataframe with a huge number of variables and I'd like to select and rename some of them. I'd like to do it iteratively by selecting them through a choosen character. Consider, I got hundreds of variables, so recalling them by indexes would be a bloodbath. Is there any solution to do this in an elegant way?

For example I got these column names:

```
 [1] "Compound.Name"  "owl.7.aa"       "owl.8.aa"       "owl.onco.72.aa" "owl.9.aa"       "owl.10.aa"     
 [7] "owl.11.aa"      "owl.12.aa"      "owl.13.aa"      "owl.7.3.aa"     "owl.8.3.aa"     "esp.8.bag"     
[13] "esp.7.bag"      "esp.72.bag"     "esp.9.bag"      "esp.10.bag"     "esp.11.bag"     "esp.12.bag"    
[19] "esp.13.bag"     "esp.7.3.bag"    "esp.8.3.bag"
```

I want to pick selectively "owl.7.aa" and "esp.7.bag" by the character "7" and replace them with a new name such as "seven" or "7". Then, I would like to do the same work with "owl.8.aa" and "esp.8.bag" replacing them with "eight", and so on.

In other words, I would like to couple experiments by their identification numbers (7, 8, 72, 9, etc.).

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it would be better f you have showe dthe expected outupt

Answer (score 0):

We can use `english`

```
library(english)
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)", ~ as.character(english(as.numeric(x))), names(df1))
```

Or it could be

```
gsubfn("[A-Za-z]+[^0-9]+(\\d+)\\..*", ~ as.character(english(as.numeric(x))),
               names(df1)
#[1] "Compound.Name" "seven"         "eight"         "seventy-two"   "nine"          "ten"          
#[7] "eleven"        "twelve"        "thirteen"      "seven"         "eight"         "eight"        
#[13] "seven"         "seventy-two"   "nine"          "ten"           "eleven"        "twelve"       
#[19] "thirteen"      "seven"         "eight"
```

#### data

```
names(df1)
c("Compound.Name", "owl.7.aa", "owl.8.aa", "owl.onco.72.aa", 
"owl.9.aa", "owl.10.aa", "owl.11.aa", "owl.12.aa", "owl.13.aa", 
"owl.7.3.aa", "owl.8.3.aa", "esp.8.bag", "esp.7.bag", "esp.72.bag", 
"esp.9.bag", "esp.10.bag", "esp.11.bag", "esp.12.bag", "esp.13.bag", 
"esp.7.3.bag", "esp.8.3.bag")
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it works! Let me ask another question about this topic. In your opinion which code could help me to replace the original names with numbers? I mean, I would figure out how to replace "owl.7.aa" with "7" rather than "seven". Thank you

Comment: @AeonRed i would use `sub(".*\\.(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", names(df1))`